# Getting the graph of the CPU and Memory usage of a server during a JMeter load test in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, server, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

The *PerfMon plugin* in JMeter allows to monitor the server health during a load test.

I have used it to obtain the following graph in JMeter’s GUI.

[image]

It shows the usage of the **CPU**, **memory** and **disk** of a server during a load test.

I want to obtain the same graph but inside Jenkins after running a job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JMeter Plugins Command Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/) in order to generate a .png file from the PerfMon csv output like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png perfmon.png --input-jtl perfmon.csv --plugin-type PerfMon --width 1024 --height 768
```

Then this `perfmon.png` file can be added to [Jenkins Artifacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/), displayed via [Image Gallery Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Image+Gallery+Plugin), etc.

You can install [Command-Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) using JMeter Plugins Manager:

[image]

Comment: I can generate the perfmon.png file. But I do not know how to add it to Jenkins Artifacts and display it.

Comment: I have written the following script  `post {
            always {
                artifacts: 'C:\\Sxx\\xxx\\workspace\\Myxxxx\\perfmon.png'
        }` but it says that it does not correspond to anything.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot suggest the fix without seeing the full pipeline